# UIScrollView from IB does not scroll

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I am trying to implement a `UIScrollView` into my application.

Note:

> ScreenSize: Freeform ( 345 ; 1000 )
>
> > Everything made with IB rather than programatically.
> >
> > > Auto Layout is activated in the application

**view hierarchy:**

[image]

I was doing the following **steps**:

1. Setting the `ViewController` to free form and 345/1000 px
2. Implementing a `UIScrollView` by dragging on screen
3. `UIScrollView` Size made 345/1000px
4. Dragging in another`UIView` named containerView.
5. All UIElements are put in the containerView.
6. Setting Constraints.

From here on I was trying several things. e.g. setting `User Defined Runtime Attributes`.

But it is still **not scrollable**.

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Did you set `scrollView.contentSize`?

Comment: I was trying to do it with ´User Defined Runtime Attributes´. How do I do it without? **edit**: tried it with         `scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(345, 400)`. did not work

Comment: ScrollView's contentSize must be greater than its frame if you want it to scroll.

Comment: you scrollView ContentSize.height is not large enough to let the scrollView to scroll!

there are some issues with your contentView constraints.

Comment: i made it to 1100 now. It is still now behaving the proper way.

Comment: Now it is working. needed to delete all Constraints.

Answer (score 1):

set bottom constraint of the last view in container view to the container view.
lastView.bottom = x + containerView.bottom